# Tricky list processing in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In a Django app of mine, users upload photos and others upvote or downvote them.

I have a list of 100 user ids that have the best aggregate photo score. For each id in this list, I want to find out the total count of photos the id has posted. I'm currently doing this in a for loop, that makes me do 100 DB calls:

```
    for user in context["object_list"]:
        count = Photo.objects.filter(owner_id=user.id).count()
```

This is very inefficient. How do I do it in one call?

Secondly, I want to turn my original list of user ids into a list of tuples, where alongwith each user id, the number of photos posted by that id is appended. E.g. [(1, 20), (2, 39), (3, 45)] etc. Please advise, I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

My photo model is:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_to_location, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

Comment: What is your `context['object_list']` queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the count from your `User` model instead (the code is more intuitive) using `annotate` with `in_bulk`

```
 from django.db.models import Count

 user_ids = [user.id for user in context["object_list"]]:

 users = User.objects.annotate(photo_count=Count('photo', distinct=True)).in_bulk(user_ids)
```

Then, you can build your list doing:

```
 users_photo_count = [(id, users[id].photo_count) for id in user_ids]
 # [(1, 20), (2, 39), (3, 45). . .]
```

Comment: User doesn't have any foreign key to photo model

Comment: @ManiKandan This works fine. Annotate works on reverse foreign key relationships. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet). Annotate can traverse foreign key relationship backwards. Please review your downvote

Comment: You have my upvote but please remember that the reverse fk relationship is named `photo_set` under the provided scheme.

Comment: Thank you @LuisMasuelli. But `_set` will not work with `annotate` as at Django 1.9, as opposed to general reverse model look-ups like `users.photo_set.all()` which are valid.

Comment: Damn it :s did they change that? Still getting into 1.9 changes... please could you point me a doc regarding that?

Comment: This [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Moses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `annotate` with `values_list()`

As you expect the output is list of tuples with user_id and their photos uploaded count

```
from django.db.models import Count

user_ids = [user.id for user in context["object_list"]]

user_photos = Photo.objects.filter(owner_id__in=user_ids).values('owner').annotate(Count('owner')).values_list('owner', 'owner__count')

# user_photos = [(1, 31), (2, 41), (3, 12)......]
```

Comment: `values` and `values_list` can be used in the same queryset?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yes, I've tested it out